# Spree 1.3: How to only show users products available in their size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I'm collecting size information from my users, so when they view the main products page, they only see products that are available in their size. I think the solution involves product scopes, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Anyone have any ideas on the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic to find the products to display is generally done by:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.1.1/core/lib/spree/core/controller_helpers/search.rb#L5-L9

An example of it being used is here:
https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.1.1/frontend/app/controllers/spree/products_controller.rb#L10

By default, it will use this code to find the products

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.1.1/core/lib/spree/core/search/base.rb#L15-L24

In order to override this, you can override the searcher_class configuration:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.1.1/core/app/models/spree/app_configuration.rb#L101-L108

The searcher class has access to the current user, and I'm assuming you've modified the current user to contain their size.

You can do a crazy-ish query to get all products of a certain size.  For example:

```
Spree::Product.joins(:variants_including_master => :option_values)
  .where('spree_option_values.presentation = ? AND
          spree_option_values.option_type_id = ?', 'XL',
          Spree::OptionType.find_by_name('tshirt-size').id)
```

Replace 'XL' with `current_user.size` or whatever you have setup, and you should have things working.

Hope that gives you a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, that was enough to get me started. It got a little more complicated because I had to check against multiple option values, but I eventually got there.